# Can I run a MySQL cluster using Amazon EC2 "Small" instances that have just 1.7GB of RAM?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

Has somebody tried using Amazon EC2 "Small" instances (the ones with 1.7GB of RAM) to install a MySQL Cluster Server? In MySQL documentation they suggest using much more RAM, but I wonder if it would work with just 1.7GB. Or maybe I should ask if the performance is "ok" with just that amount of RAM. Or will it run, but too slow?

Note: I'm aware of the RDBS service that Amazon offers, using MySQL. But I would prefer building my own cluster using a pair of small instances, if it is not too expensive or too slow.

Comment: It will run fine, depending on your load. Look at their new medium instance (not high-cpu medium). If you find it a bit slow on the small, simply stop your instance, restart it as a medium.  Btw, this question is better suited for serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql Cluster uses RAM a lot so 1.7RAM is very little and I would use it only for testing or for small sites. With those small instances you could run Percona XtraDB Cluster which support s MyIsam and Innodb. Witn MySql Cluster you have to use the NDB engine